# HTML5 new elements

Tags: html, syntax

I have realized that the new elements in html 5 such as:

- Header
- Nav
- Footer

which currently replace the divs.  After implementing these I have realized that they only work on Mozilla however they do not pick up on IE.

How do come across this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE8 doesn't support those new elements, you need to use the HTML5shiv:

ref: https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

If you're interested in the details of how it works:

ref: http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-shiv/

Answer (score 1):

Header, nav, article, section, footer are semantic elements introduced in html5. thus IE 8 and below doesn't support these elements. Either write this js code in your page, or use html5shiv.js. here is my article on IE compatibility
http://tutorial.techaltum.com/html4-vs-html5.html